# Python3 Requests ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', OSError("(104, 'ECONNRESET')",)) with a specific URL

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, anaconda

This is my code.

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://academic.oup.com/journals')
```

then I got the error below;

```
ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', OSError("(104, 'ECONNRESET')",))
```

Why I got the error?
What should I do?
the Request works well with other URLs like https://www.google.com

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try specifying a user-agent in the HTTP header:

```
❯❯❯ python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Sep 14 2016, 11:28:32) 
[GCC 6.2.1 20160901 (Red Hat 6.2.1-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import requests
>>> headers = requests.utils.default_headers()
>>> headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36'
>>> r = requests.get('https://academic.oup.com/journals', headers=headers)
>>> r
<Response [200]>
```

Also, make sure you follow the rules mentioned in the [website's robots.txt](https://academic.oup.com/robots.txt)